# how to count the number of keys in a json at a specific depth

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file and would like to perform a calculation using values from keys at a particular depth. In my case the first value is at:

```
json.children[0].children[0].children[0]
```

Is there a way to traverse the json object at a specific depth?

Comment: please add some data, the result and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tree search to process any object including deserialised json. This simple function returns names of keys of object at given depth. It doesn't work with strings as values but I think you can get general idea of solution from this code.

```js
json = {
    a: {
        aa: 123,
        bb: 456
    },
    b: {},
    c: 123
}
const checkAtDepth = (obj, depth) => {
    const result = [];
    const dfs = (node, maxDepth = 0, nodeName) => {
        if (maxDepth === 0) {
            result.push(nodeName);
            return;
        }
        Object.keys(node).forEach(key => {
            dfs(node[key], maxDepth-1, key);
        })
    }

    dfs(obj, depth);
    return result;
}

console.log( checkAtDepth(json, 1) )
console.log( checkAtDepth(json, 2) )
console.log( checkAtDepth(json, 3) )
```